# Can a query hint be added to a LinqDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linqdatasource

Legacy ASP.NET application uses a LinqDataSource to populate a GridView, but querying the SQL Server view is slow unless OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION')) is added to the query.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server"    
    ContextTypeName="MyDataContext"
    OrderBy="Column1, Column2" 
    TableName="MyTable"
    Where="MyId == @Pid &amp;&amp; Oid == @Oid">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Pid" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Oid" Type="Int32" />
     </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Is there any way to add an option/hint to a LinqDataSource?

Comment: Perhaps trying to work out why the view doesn't "behave" with the new cardinality estimator would be an idea still. Does the view use nested views? Perhaps it has a non-SARGable clause? Using the hint feels like kicking the can further down the street.

Comment: I think you can call a procedure inside the LinqDataSource, and there you can use whatever hints you want. Don't you have indexes on MyId / Oid though?